# Can I print a specific page of a tiled document on Adobe InDesign CC?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, proofing

I have a rather large (5 by 1 meters) banner and I'd like to see an specific section of it in real size. I know I can tile the document on the print dialog on InDesign to be able to print it in real size in (many) A4 sheets. Can I specify one page of the automatic tile to be printed? How?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try "printing" the tiled document from InDesign to a PDF file, then you'll have a PDF file with multiple pages, and you can choose whichever you want to actually print, and send that one to the printer.
NOTE: "Printing" to a PDF file can mess with your colors a little see [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/25345/15321).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use InDesign's own system for printing tiles manually. Make sure your rulers are visible (command-R). Put your cursor in the very top lefthand corner (you'll see a little cross made of dotted lines) and click and drag. This resets where your ruler begins. Drag to the top of the section you want to print. Go to "Print" then "Setup," check "tile" and use the dropdown menu to choose "Manual." This will print the section of the page that you indicated with the ruler--you'll see a map of your page size and where it hits your document in the print window.

To set your rulers back to normal when you're done, just double-click in that same top lefthand corner; the position will go back to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Apex gave a valid option to get around this.

IN CASE YOU HAVE ADOBE ILLUSTRATOR:

What I would do is to export a PDF and then **place** it in illustrator into an Artboard the same size, then if you try and print from illustrator you will realize that you can span the preview window to chose which part you want to print.

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer, I actually tried to do exactly what you're describing on InDesign because I remembered doing it on other software